# How to setup Single Instance of WhatsApp Business API Client

Tags: docker, docker-compose, whatsapp, whatsapi, facebook-business-manager

I had cloned these file as per [facebook instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/dev-single-instance#step-7--register-the-whatsapp-business-api-client)

And then Step 1: Create a biz Directory for the Setup Scripts

```
mkdir ~/biz; cd ~/biz;
```

Step 2: Get the WhatsApp Business API Client Configuration Files

```
   db.env

docker-compose.yml

multiconnect-compose.yml
```

Step 3: Set the WA_API_VERSION Environment Variable

```
export WA_API_VERSION=2.31.5
```

Step 4: Start the WhatsApp Business API Client

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The resulting output should look like the following:

```
Recreating whatsbusinessapi_db_1 ... done
Creating whatsbusinessapi_wacore_1 ... done
Creating whatsbusinessapi_waweb_1  ... done
```

Step 5: Verify Containers Are Running

```
docker-compose ps
```

output :

```
          Name                         Command               State                     Ports                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
whatsbusinessapi_db_1       docker-entrypoint.sh -p 54 ...   Up      5000/tcp, 5432/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->6000/tcp
whatsbusinessapi_wacore_1   /opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_ ...   Up      6250/tcp, 6251/tcp, 6252/tcp, 6253/tcp    
whatsbusinessapi_waweb_1    /opt/whatsapp/bin/wait_on_ ...   Up      0.0.0.0:9090->443/tcp
```

By default, the Webapp container will be running on port 9090 (https://localhost:9090)
as per facebook but when i tried https://localhost:9090
[image]

So anyone have idea please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WhatsApp Web Business Tool is deprecated since v2.29.1
You can only interact with your instance via REST API. You can leverage our Postman collection for this https://github.com/fbsamples/WhatsApp-Business-API-Postman-Collection

Sounds like you are ready to proceed with Step 6

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/installation/dev-single-instance#step-6--login-and-authenticate